# How to remove a required validation on the fly in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Already I have this schema created. Mostly of the time I need that the field `v1` must be required, but under extraordinaries conditions the field `v1` does not need it. How I do that?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var MonographSchema = new Schema({
        v1: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        v3: [
            {
                _id: false,
                _: String,
                a: String,
                b: String,
                c: [String],
                t: Number
            }
        ]
});

mongoose.model('Monograph', MonographSchema);



var Monograph = mongoose.model('Monograph');   

 var monograph1 = new Monograph({ 
         v1: '001ab',   
         v3: [
              {'_': 'BR1.1', 'a': '1.00', 'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.1', 'e.2'], 't': '1001'},
              {'_': 'BR67.1', 'a': '614.32', 'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.2'], 't': '25'},
              {'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.2'], 't': '25'}
             ]        
});

 var monograph2 = new Monograph({    
         v3: [
              {'_': 'BR1.1', 'a': '1.00', 'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.1', 'e.2'], 't': '1001'},
              {'_': 'BR67.1', 'a': '614.32', 'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.2'], 't': '25'},
              {'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.2'], 't': '25'}
             ]        
});

monograph1.save(); //all fine
monograph2.save(); //I get an error
```

How I can unset the `required: true` of `v1` on the fly?

Comment: just remove `required: true`

Comment: I can't do that because I use the same schema to validate different types of documents, each of them use only a part of the schema (NOTE: The schema is much bigger than I showed). There are documents that use certain required fields, and other documents do not use them. Because of I need to remove the fields that are required when I have documents that does not use them. That is possible on the fly?

Comment: you can attach custom validate event with `validate: function`

Answer (score 3):

Well maybe not "turn off on the fly", but you can just call one of the general `.update()` forms instead of `.save()` which does not employ the validation of pre-save hooks:

```
  var async = require('async'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

  var MonographSchema = new Schema({
  v1: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  v3: [
    {
      _id: false,
      _: String,
      a: String,
      b: String,
      c: [String],
      t: Number
    }
  ]
});

mongoose.model('Monograph', MonographSchema);

var Monograph = mongoose.model('Monograph');
var monograph1 = new Monograph({
  v1: '001ab',
  v3: [
    {'_': 'BR1.1', 'a': '1.00', 'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.1', 'e.2'], 't': '1001'},
    {'_': 'BR67.1', 'a': '614.32', 'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.2'], 't': '25'},
    {'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.2'], 't': '25'}
  ]
});

var monograph2 = new Monograph({
  v3: [
    {'_': 'BR1.1', 'a': '1.00', 'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.1', 'e.2'], 't': '1000'},
    {'_': 'BR67.1', 'a': '614.32', 'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.2'], 't': '25'},
    {'b': 'T17a', 'c': ['v.2'], 't': '25'}
  ]
});


async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Monograph.findByIdAndUpdate(
        monograph1._id,
        { "$set": monograph1.toObject() },
        { "upsert": true },
        function(err,doc) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(JSON.stringify( doc, undefined, 2 ));
          callback();
        }
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      Monograph.findByIdAndUpdate(
        monograph2._id,
        { "$set": monograph2.toObject() },
        { "upsert": true },
        function(err,doc) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log( JSON.stringify( doc, undefined, 2 ));
          callback();
        }
      );
    }
  ]
);
```

So both of those calls are going to work without failure:

```
{
  "_id": "542a41389330a912140c20c9",
  "v1": "001ab",
  "__v": 0,
  "v3": [
    {
      "_": "BR1.1",
      "a": "1.00",
      "b": "T17a",
      "t": 1001,
      "c": [
        "v.1",
        "e.2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_": "BR67.1",
      "a": "614.32",
      "b": "T17a",
      "t": 25,
      "c": [
        "v.2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "b": "T17a",
      "t": 25,
      "c": [
        "v.2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": "542a41389330a912140c20ca",
  "__v": 0,
  "v3": [
    {
      "_": "BR1.1",
      "a": "1.00",
      "b": "T17a",
      "t": 1000,
      "c": [
        "v.1",
        "e.2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_": "BR67.1",
      "a": "614.32",
      "b": "T17a",
      "t": 25,
      "c": [
        "v.2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "b": "T17a",
      "t": 25,
      "c": [
        "v.2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So the "validation" and other methods are in fact "bound" to the `.save()` method. If you don't use it then the methods don't get called. Oh and you can ask "virtual" fields to be output from `.toObject()` calls, so there is no need to loose that if you use it.

So either that or just removing the "required" attribute is probably your best approach, but this is possible, just as long as you take more care:

```
async.series(
  [
    // Is valid anyway
    function(callback) {
      monograph1.save(function(err,doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log( JSON.stringify( doc, undefined, 2 ) );
        callback();
      });
    },
    // Remove the validators and replace
    function(callback) {
      var hold =  monograph2.schema.paths.v1.validators;
      monograph2.schema.paths.v1.validators = [];
      monograph2.save(function(err,doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log( JSON.stringify( doc, undefined, 2 ) );
        monograph2.schema.paths.v1.validators = hold;
        callback();
      });
    },
    // With validators will fail
    function(callback) {
      monograph2.save(function(err,doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log( JSON.stringify( doc, undefined, 2 ) );
        callback();
      });
    }
  ]
);
```

What this shows is that if you remove the "validators" array from the schema path you are using then there will be no check. You could just remove the "required" validator, but for the presented schema that is the only validator present at that path.

Care must be taken as this is a "global" change to the attached schema of the model and until this is replaced then the validator will be considered not to be there. This also means that you are not modifying the "instance" of the object, but the attached object that is used by all instances. So while this is "turned off" is it "off everywhere".

So the real options break down to:

1. Either live with loosing all type checking and validation on other fields.
2. Live with not having a required attribute on the field to begin with.
3. Accept the dangers of manipulating the object schema validation methods

Untimately you can "temporarily" remove this check, but probably not in the way that you might expect and that alone has it's pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With this solution I can insert the way I want, but in this way I lose other important validations that I have in the schema, and that is not what I want. Apparently "turn off on the fly" `required: true` is not possible. :(

Comment: @in3pi2 Well I did say that this bypasses validation. I even did try to set the schema property directly, but to no avail. There is nothing stopping you inspecting the schema properties manually and then performing your own validation logic around that. Strapped for time right now for an example, and actually typing on phone.

Comment: thanks anyway. But I chose to remove the `required: true` from the squema and create a custom required in a `validation` function. I think that would work too.

Comment: @in3pi2 Turns out that it is possible to just turn off the validation for a single path. Probably not recommended though. More notes on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Followup on Niel Lunn's answer, set "strict" option to false in the update query like so:

```
{ upsert: true, strict: false }
```

I hope this helps anyone that finds it.